# Shadowbox not loading/working

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery, shadowbox

I downloaded the standalone version of shadowbox for images with css support. I loaded the files onto my website server and put the following codes on my page:

HTML head for webpage:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init();
</script>
```

HTML link on my webpage:

```
<a href="files/IMG00237-20110525-1138.jpg" rel="shadowbox">My Image</a>
```

Nothing happens with this code. Shadowbox doesnt load....nor does the pic load in shadowbox when I click the link. What am I doing wrong?

What I am trying to achieve once i get this to work is to, upon page load, have shadowbox automatically show and start scrolling through a gallery of photos (i hate the click link thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the latest shadowbox and used your code above and it worked fine.

Are you sure the paths are correct to both shadowbox and the image.
Have you checked the console logs?

In terms of setting it up so it opens on load they have an example on their website...

EDIT:
Player needs to be set to "img" and the content only needs to be the path to the image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
    // let's skip the automatic setup because we don't have any
    // properly configured link elements on the page
    skipSetup: true
});

window.onload = function() {

    // open a welcome message as soon as the window loads
    Shadowbox.open({
        content:    'https://www.google.co.nz/images/srpr/logo11w.png',
        player:     "img",
        title:      "Welcome",
        height:     350,
        width:      350
    });

};
</script>
```

Comment: ok. i was more specific with the path to the javascript and css files. now it FINALLY loads up shadowbox upon click of the link.....however

Comment: I tried that window.onload funtion in my html head and it doesnt do anything......nothing at all

Comment: Try the example above. I copied this straight from their website. you could easily modify this to load up an image instead of text e.g.

content:    '<img src="" title="" alt="" />',

Comment: yep...screen darkens with that new code you put in ...but it doesn't show shadowbox.....just darkens the screen...weird

Comment: I put this into the head of my page but all it does is darkens the screen:     <script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
  skipSetup: true
});

window.onload = function() {

   Shadowbox.open({
     content:    '<img src="files/IMG00237-20110525-1138.jpg" title="" alt="" />',
     player:     "html",
     title:      "Welcome",
     height:     350,
     width:      350
   });

};
</script>

Comment: yes!!! it worked! thank you so much...ima add more images to that code and see if I can get all 20 images to show up in the shadowbox...this is soooooo awesome!

Comment: Myles, an update if you see this I could use a little more help:

Comment: I cannot figure how to have a "gallery" or bunch of photos load up in shadowbox on initial page load. I only got that one photo. I've been looking all over the shadowbox site and can't find anything relevant. I have another issue as well, but i wanna fix this first if possible

Comment: Might pay to ask another question as this is kind of off topic now.

Comment: myles, i posted the new question....im sure you know the answer. more rep points for you